# как получить callback в конце css анимации?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, css-animation, animate

По клику на элемент `first` добавляется стиль `animation = "move 5s";`. Как получить `callback` в конце `css` анимации, что бы обнулить стиль? Можно докидывать модификатор в виде класса у которого будут стили, или может через атрибут и его потом обнулять, но как получить `callback`?

P.S: Ради наглядности, обнуляю стиль через `setTimeout`.

```js
function getId(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id);
}

function getStyle(elem) {
 return getComputedStyle(elem);
}

function setStyle(elem) {
 return elem.style;
}

let firstElem = getId("first");

firstElem.addEventListener('click', function() {
 setStyle(firstElem).animation = "move 5s";
 setTimeout(function() {
  setStyle(firstElem).animation = "none";
 }, 5000);
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #3B3738;
 padding: 10px;
}

.elem {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #512;
 width: 150px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
 //animation: move 5s;
 left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 &:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
}

@keyframes move {
 50% {
  left: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="elem" id="first">First</div>
```

Comment: Увы но колбека у анимации css нет. только через setTimeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть два событие, которое срабатывает после завершения анимации, можно подвязаться к ним.

1)  `transitionend` - срабатывает когда заканчивает свое выполнение свойство CSS `transition`

2) `animationend`  - срабатывает когда заканчивает свое выполнение свойство CSS `animation`, соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо, это частично мне помогает, но тут только отслеживается свойство `transition`, а я анимировал через `@keyframes` и `animate`.

Comment: Есть и animationend

Comment: напиши это в ответ и я отмечу его. спасибо тебе.

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы иметь возможность вызывать `callback` после завершения функции, вы можете использовать `requestAnimationFrame`. Например:

```js
function getId(id) {
 return document.getElementById(id);
}
let firstElem = getId("first");

firstElem.onclick = function() {
    animate(function(timePassed) {
        firstElem.style.left = timePassed / 5 + 'px';
    }, 2000);
};

// Рисует функция draw
// Продолжительность анимации duration
function animate(draw, duration) {
  var start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
    // определить, сколько прошло времени с начала анимации
    var timePassed = time - start;

      // возможно небольшое превышение времени, в этом случае зафиксировать конец
    if (timePassed > duration) timePassed = duration;

    // нарисовать состояние анимации в момент timePassed
    draw(timePassed);

    // если время анимации не закончилось - запланировать ещё кадр
    if (timePassed < duration) {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
    //иначе показываем сообщение что анимация завершилась
    //или вызываем какой нибудь callback
      firstElem.style.left = 0
      alert('анимация завершена')
    }

  });
}
```

```css
body {
 background: #3B3738;
 padding: 10px;
}
.elem {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #512;
 width: 150px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
 //animation: move 5s;
 left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elem" id="first">First</div>
```

Подробнее читайте [в учебнике про js-анимации](https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation), еще [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) и [тут](http://html5.by/blog/what-is-requestanimationframe/).

Comment: Спасибо, но я работал конкретно с `css` анимацией, а точнее с `animation: move 5s;`. Я в этом примере добавляю стили через js, но в дальнейшем буду классом, но суть тут в том, что бы получить `callback` в конце css анимации, а не анимировать через `requestAnimationFrame`. Ниже есть ответ, но он только отслеживает свойство `transition`.