# Как отложить время до отправки формы

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть форма для регистрации. При нажатии на кнопку "Зарегистрироваться" должна быть анимация, но она не успевает проиграться, потому что  сразу переносит на следующую страницу. Как отложить время до отправки формы?

Comment: Дождаться окончания анимации, например. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/795662/256824

Comment: можно использовать setTimeout в js )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через animationend. Это событие вывзывается когда CSS анимация достигает конца своего активного периода, который вычисляется как (animation-duration * animation-iteration-count) + animation-delay.

```
var animEndHandler = target.onanimationend;
target.onanimationend = Function
```

A Function вызывается, когда происходит событие animationend, указывающее, что анимация CSS начинается с цели, где целевой объект является HTML-элементом (HTMLElement), документ (Document) или окно (Window). Функция получает в качестве входного параметра один параметр: AnimationEvent объект, описывающий событие, которое произошло.